# Boost max weight matching run time explosion

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory

I have a graph with 16 vertices and all of them are connected to each other (120 edges) with equal weights. When I try to run boost max weight matching on this graph, it hangs indefinitely. All edge weights are ints. I want to know if this is an issue with boost or its expected for max weight matching to take very long to converge on cliques. Also, changing the weights of each edge to be different fixes the issue. Here's the link to godbolt  https://godbolt.org/z/Mbf84Yva7 .

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bipartite.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/maximum_weighted_matching.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/max_cardinality_matching.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
                              boost::vecS,
                              boost::undirectedS,
                              boost::no_property,
                              EdgeWeightProperty>
  my_graph;

int main() {
      my_graph g;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++i) {
        boost::add_vertex(g);
      }
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 16 ; ++j) {
            if(i < j) {
                boost::add_edge(i, j, EdgeWeightProperty(5), g);
            }
        }
      }
    std::vector<boost::graph_traits<my_graph>::vertex_descriptor> mate1(boost::num_vertices(g));
    std::cout<<" Running Boost max weight matching on boost graph " << std::endl;
    std::cout<<" Num vertices "<< boost::num_vertices(g) << std::endl;
    std::cout<<" Num edges "<< boost::num_edges(g) << std::endl;
    // boost::edmonds_maximum_cardinality_matching(g, &mate1[0]);
    boost::maximum_weighted_matching(g, &mate1[0]);
    std::cout<<" Done running max weight matching on boost graph" << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your graph there is not one answer. If a match contains every vertex , then the match has equal weight to every other such match.

So what is the point?  It is a meaningless problem.

If you want to guard against the hang, add a little loop over edges to check that they are not all equally weighted, before calling the boost graph method.

Comment: sure. but what if all the edges in the graph have the same weight except for 1? Is this really only an issue when every single edge has the same weight?

Comment: To answer questions like that, you do not need stackoverflow.  Run a test and find out for yourself.